How do I reassemble an unzipped xlam file?
I am trying to change the name of the tab that appears in the ribbon of Excel 2016 of a custom addin (xlam file) that was created before me. I found a stack overflow answer (How do you rename the tab of a add-in in Excel when customizing does not work?) that said to unzip the xlam file and I was able to edit the xml file that contained the tab name in the unzipped results (in the customui directory). Now I am trying to reassemble the xlam file but I don't know how.
I tried adding the unzipped files and directories to archive using 7zip but the resulting file was recognized as potentially corrupted and did not work at all. How do I reassemble it?

It sounds like you're doing the right things. When you say "potentially corrupted", do you mean Excel didn't like it or that you couldn't even open it in, say, 7zip? If the former, try inspecting the zip file contents before and after; maybe you're "zipping up" one folder too high (i.e. zipping the parent folder instead of the files)? You could also try editing the file "in place" - 7zip supports this (open the archive, edit a specific file and then save it; you will probably need admin permissions for this).

Have you tried changing the file extension from .7zip to .xlam?

When I say potentially corrupted, I get the message "Excel cannot open the file ... because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file".
When I edited the file "in place" using 7zip I was able to change the tab name! I could edit the file containing the tab name of the xlam add in. Then I saved it and the xlam add in worked with the tab name changed to what I set it to. Thank you!
